# How to list all values in a while loop when it breaks in Python?

Tags: python

Here is a simple case.

```
i = 0
while i <=3:
   y = i * 2
   i += 1
   break
print(y)
```

The result inside the while loop is (0,2,4,6). However, when I print the result out of loop, I can get the last value of 6 only. So how can I get the whole value even I am out of while loop?

Comment: Initialize an empty list before the loop.  Inside the loop, append the current number to the list.  After the loop ends, the list will have all the numbers.

Comment: This is because you are redefining a value to y every time the loop runs so I would recommend you put the values in a list and then print each of the list items with a loop.

Comment: _The result inside the while loop is (0,2,4,6)_ No it isn't.  The loop has a `break` and will only execute once.

Comment: Yeah I already get it. I removed the break n now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize an empty list and then append the value of `y` into the list.
Finally print the list after the `while` loop.

```
i = 0
ar = []
while i <=3:
   y = i * 2
   i += 1
   ar.append(y)
print(ar)
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: Yeah I see. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
i = 0
y = []
while i <=3:
   y.append(i * 2)
   i += 1
print(y)
```

This should work fine.

Comment: @JiangYunke, could you mark this answer as the correct answer, please?

Comment: Yup, Thanks. Happy to help.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using break, use a list, something like this:

```
i = 0
number_list = []
while i <= 3:
    i += 1
    y = i*2
    number_list.append(y)

for x in number_list:
    print(x)
```

Comment: Yeah I see. By using append(). Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
y = []

while i <=3:
   y.append(i * 2)
   i += 1

print(y)
```

This should work :)

```
Output:

[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: No problem! What you missed out on what that you added `break` which would break the look without it going through 4 times. And you didn't initialise a list (y) and used a plain variable which can only hold 1 value. Choose this answer as the final answer of your question to help others :) Thanks.